# Is sparse categorical crossentropy support arbitrary custom label encoding?

Tags: tensorflow, loss, one-hot-encoding, categorical-crossentropy, label-encoding

As we know that in AI tools like tensorflow has loss named `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` which bassically `categorical_crossentropy`. The different is, `categorical_crossentropy` for one-hot encoding while `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` is for label encoding or integer encoding. In a nutshell, `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` will convert the label encoding to one-hot encoding at the end CMIIW.

Encoding label encoding commonly use incremental integer such as `[0, 1, 0, 2, 0]` that has unique value `(0, 1, 2)` therefore it is 3 classes.

So I want to confirm if `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` support custom label encoding such as `[0, 27, 27, 0, 0, 24, 24, 0, 1, 1,]` that has unique value `(0, 1, 24, 27)` or 4 classes; in any tensor processing tools.